# i have an error at setText in adapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> brands;

public AdapterListView(ArrayList<String> brands, Context context) {
    this.brands = brands;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return brands.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_listview,null);
    ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    lv.setText(brands.get(i));

    return view;
}
}
```

setText has error and displaying (cannot resolve method,settext(java.lag.string))

my message fragment class is given bellow am actually trying to set a listview

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);


    brands.add("microsoft");
    brands.add("ios" );
    brands.add("android");
    AdapterListView adapter = new AdapterListView(brands,getActivity());

    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

i need to print the list brands.is thr any error in the way i set the listview

Comment: How can you have setText of ListView? You are creating adatper for listview and inside it also you are declaring object of listview

Comment: can u pls suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
lv.setText(brands.get(i));
```

you have to take `TextView` in your `R.layout.activity_listview`
and than code should be

```
TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
tv.setText(brands.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

> setText has error and displaying (cannot resolve
>   method,settext(java.lag.string))

Because `setText` method is not defined in `ListView` class.

Use TextView,EditText,Button like views for using `setText` method